# Ansible nested lookup

Tags: ansible, jinja2, lookup

I am trying to do a lookup of vars at 3 levels of nesting:

```
aws:
  dev_vault:
    us-west-2:
      secret1:             ...
      secret2:             .......
```

Lookup syntax:

```
{{ lookup('vars', deployment_target)[app_env_vault][region]['secret1'] }}
```

It says:

```
 FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute u'dev_vault'"}

app_env_vault = 'dev_vault'
```

2 levels of nesting works fine. But 3rd level of nesting is not working.

2-level nesting:

```
dev_vault:
  us-west-2:
    secret1:             ...
    secret2:             .......

{{ lookup('vars', app_env_vault)[region]['secret1'] }}
```

The above works fine and resolves to secret1.

Ansible version : 2.9

Comment: 3rd level of nesting works fine, what is your actually content of dictionary? What version of Ansible ?

Comment: You've shown nothing from your attempt where "2 levels of nesting works fine", so we don't know what that means. You also haven't included all of the relevant variables; if I take your sample data and add what I assume those variables are, I cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: @user1098490 Updated answer.

Comment: Please makes sure your spaces/tabs is correct when adding an additional key ( `aws`) to your dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I recreated a simple playbook based on your information:

```yaml
---
 - hosts: localhost                                                              
   connection: local                                                             
   vars:                                                                         
     deployment_target: aws                                                      
     app_env_vault: dev_vault                                                  
     region: us-west-2                                                           
     secret: secret1                                                             
     aws:                                                                        
       dev_vault:                                                                
         us-west-2:                                                              
           secret1: 123                                                          
           secret2: 321                                                          
   tasks:                                                                        
     - name: Print value                                                              
       debug:                                                                    
         msg: "{{ lookup('vars', deployment_target)[app_env_vault][region][secret] }}"
```

Output:

```
PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Print value] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "123"
}
```

If try to comment out the `dev_vault` key from the dictionary:

```
PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Print value] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'dev_vault'\n\nThe error appears to be in 'test.yml': line 15, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  tasks:\n    - name: Print value\n      ^ here\n"}
```

As you can see I get the same exact error. As mentioned in the comment above (@lioweryson), make sure you're able to do "2 levels of nesting" and verify the existence of your dictionary keys before trying third level.